# mdfind query weird behaviour

Tags: macos, shell, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, spotlight

Look at this mdfind query:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFSName = "Pages.app" || kMDItemFSName = "Keynote.app" || kMDItemFSName = "Numbers.app"'
```

Is there something wrong with it? Perhaps logical `OR` - `||` which is not documented by Apple on `mdfind` man page?

In 99% cases, `mdfind` returns three file paths / locations of each `iwork` app (or nothing when they are not installed).

```
/Applications/iWork '09/Pages.app   
/Applications/iWork '09/Keynote.app  
/Applications/iWork '09/Numbers.app
```

But in ~1-5% (10.8.2) I get this from `mdfind`:

```
/Applications/iWork '09/Keynote.app  
/Applications/Mail.app  
/Applications/Messages.app  
/Applications/Utilities/Migration Assistant.app  
/Applications/Notes.app  
...  
/Library/Scripts/Printing Scripts/Convert To PDF.scpt  
/Library/Scripts/Printing Scripts/Convert To PostScript.scpt  
/Library/Scripts/Printing Scripts/Print Window With Subfolders.scpt  
/Library/Scripts/Printing Scripts/Print Window.scpt  
...  
/System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GKNavbarBackButtonNormalLandscape.png  
/System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GKNavbarBackButtonNormalLandscape@2x.png*  

------------ List goes on (tons of stuff) ------------
```

Is there something wrong with my `mdfind` query, OR is there something wrong with `Spotlight database`?

Certainly a possibility: There is serious bug in Spotlight introduced with `10.7.5` and `10.8.2` updates (check https://discussions.apple.com/message/19863234#19863234 )

Thanks :-)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it yesterday, but now it listed about 300000 files after the applications. (I'm on 10.8.2.)

Comment: At least one of the 10.7.5 Spotlight issues has been fixed - http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1599

Comment: This is a bug as far as I can tell. Happens on 10.7.5 and 10.8.2, fully updated, but does NOT happen on 10.6.8.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is going on here. It seems that Spotlight is broken for OR searching on kMDItemFS* ?

I hand created an OR based Spotlight search in the Finder - it fails.

I downloaded HoudahSpot and made a simple 'Filename' is Pages.app OR Filename is Keynote.app query and got the same results - over 50,000

So it does not look like its merely a bug in mdfind's interpretation of the query.

As a further clue:
Any item with FS in the name - example kMDItemFSName - is not stored in the Spotlight Database, so queries take much longer.

```
 mdfind "kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == 'com.apple.iWork.Pages'  || kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == 'com.apple.iWork.Keynote'"
```

works about 1000x faster on my computer.

In this guide which is 5 years or so old, they mention using a single | for OR, but that does not work for me on 10.8.2 
http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2006/01/04/mdfind.html

Comment: +1 on the performance cost of FS items. You can use kMDItemDisplayName for file name as well. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Yes, you can use kMDItemDisplayName, but it can be radically different than the file name. Pages.app has a display name of Pages, and "....Library/Mail/.../248747.emlx has a display name of "Re: Purchase"

Comment: Can you comment on where "Any item with FS in the name is not stored in the Spotlight Database" is documented?